# PHP script to execute exec

Tags: php, exec

I am writing a PHP script to upload a file that execute other c files by using system calls `fork()`, and `exec()`, and `execl()`.
Unfortunately execl() function did not work.
In more details, the PHP script , execute `exec()` function as:

```
$output =shell_exec('./app/p1';
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; )
```

to execute p1 which is the executable file of p1.c, and  the p1.c program calls execl() as:

```
execl("./p2", "./p2", "a.param","test.txt", NULL);
```

to execute p2 which is the executable file of p2.c. As the result execl() in p1.c is not executed, and p2.c is not executed. 
Any suggestions.

Comment: Is p1 executed at all? Therefore does other commands work in p1?

Comment: `shell_exec()` id disabled if PHP is running in `safe_mode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). Are you sure that your PHP engine has `safe_mode` disabled?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [`shell_exec` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), this function is only enabled if `safe_mode` is disabled in PHP configuration.

To disable it, (only for [PHP prior to 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)), you must include the following line in `php.ini`:

```
safe_mode = Off
```

Another possible problem could come from current path. You're calling the binnaries using relative paths (`./app/p1` and `./p2`). Are you sure that these binnaries are in the current working directory?

To get rid of this problem, simply use the file's full path in both cases.